# Create empty horizontal space

Tags: thesis

I am writing an abstract page for my thesis and need to include names of my supervisors at the the top of the page. I am at a loss as to how to input the names so the align vertically. Here is the code:

```
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} 

\begin{center}{THREE ESSAYS ON THE INFORMAL SECTOR}\end{center}
\vspace{0.3in}
\ssp
\noindent Musah Khalid \hfill  Advisors:\\ \noindent University of Manitoba, 2017 \hfill Dr. John Serieux 
 \\ \noindent*                                     \hfill Dr. Ryan Godwin

\dsp
\paragraph*{} (Abstract Here)
```

I want the names of my supervisors to align vertically at the left. How do I do that?

Here is the entire code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{uomthesis}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 0}
\usepackage{bm} % for boldface fonts
\usepackage{listings} % for code verbatim
% Added packages:
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows,backgrounds,trees,shapes,automata]
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating, rotfloat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%
\usepackage{times}
%
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
% 
\makeatletter
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother
\def\dsp{\def\baselinestretch{2.0}\large\normalsize}
\def\ssp{\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\large\normalsize}          
\dsp
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus.33em minus.07em}
%
\include{com}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
%*****************************************************
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C}
%*******************  Front Matter  *******************
\begin{frontmatter}
    \include{PhD_01_TitlePage} % title, approval page, copyright page
    \include{PhD_05_TOC} % TOC, LOT, LOF
    \include{PhD_02_Abstract}
    \include{PhD_04_Acknowledgements}
    \include{PhD_03_Dedication} % not usual in UoMuelph thesis  
\end{frontmatter}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you include all your code, starting with `\documentclass` up until `\end{document}`, necessary to reproduce your situation? This is so that we can fully compile your code - you also seem to have some unknown (to me at least) commands `\ssp` and `\dsp`.

Comment: Sorry I am new here. I am using a .cls file. Is there a way to upload the file?

Comment: I have edited it to include more information. Does that work?

Comment: Where can we get `uomthesis.cls`?

Comment: For future reference: try to reduce your example to the smallest and simplest document that shows your problem and can compile. That's easier for people here to work with. I understand if you are new to LaTeX it can be hard to guess what matters and what doesn't, and someone will shout at you either way, but it does help!

Comment: @Bernard it originally uogthesis than I am attempting to modify. Not done with it yet but you can get uogthesis online.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you want here, and I suspect most of the class stuff is just cruft. My basic approach would be to use two parboxes, one to hold the left material, one the right hand side (if I correctly understand your wishes). To ensure the right hand edge of the right hand side is aligned with the right margin, we measure the longest text in the box (by setting it in a box and using that box's width).

What this is doing:

- `\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{Your Name\\University of Manitoba}` creates a box, 40% as wide as the text, with two lines: your name and the university.
- `\hfill` inserts stretch horizontal space which pushes the next box to the right hand side of the page.
- `\parbox{\wd0}{Advisers://One Doctor//Another Doctor}` sets another box. This time it is set to a width just wide enough to accommodate the longest text that has to be fitted in, so that ends right at the edge of the page.

By putting the material in boxes, we are able to treat each box as a sort of "unit" so that there is a line with three units: two boxes and a bit of stretchy space, but the boxes are special because they contain (in each case) several lines of text.

One point: don't use `Dr. Mangelwurzel`, used `Dr.~Mangelwurzel` or your spacing and line-breaking may go wrong: not so much a point here, but a general one.

Anyway, something like this works in `article` and would *probably* work in your class as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}{THREE ESSAYS ON THE INFORMAL SECTOR}\end{center}
\vspace{0.3in}
\noindent
\setbox0=\hbox{Dr.~Ryan Godwin}%
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{Musah Khalid\\University of Manitoba}\hfill
\parbox{\wd0}{Advisers:\\Dr.~John Serieux\\Dr.~Ryan Godwin}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I am struggling to attach the screenshot:). Will try and get it attached so you can see what I refer to.

Comment: I don't think you can attach screenshots to comments. Can you describe where the spaces are?

Comment: There is a horizontal space between Musah Khalid and University of Manitoba that extends to the right.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like a paragraph indent. Try wrapping the `\parboxes` in a set of braces `{ }` and add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` **inside** the braces at the start of them. Does it go away?

Comment: Any way of removing it?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think it can be a paragraph indent now I think about it, so I'm flummoxed. You mean "University of Manitoba" is shifted to the right? How much? Are you sure you have no stray spaces?

Comment: No the space goes between Musah Khalid and University of Manitoba and John Serieux and Ryan Godwin.

Comment: {\parbox \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} {0.4\textwidth}{Musah Khalid\\University of Manitoba}}\hfill
     {\parbox \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} {\wd0}{Advisers:\\Dr.~John Serieux\\Dr.~Ryan Godwin}} 

No luck.

Comment: No. That's quite wrong. Sorry. I am confusing you. Forget the `\parindent' stuff altogether. I thought you *wanted* space between the stuff on the left and the stuff on the right! I'm afraid I'm not understanding what you want. I'm going to edit the answer to explain a bit and hope that gets you on the right track.